# WPF save as dialog ... in a view?

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

My application has a wizard with some steps used to export data.

I want one of these steps to be the "Save as" step where the user choose the location on disk where the results will be exported.

I don't want to pop the save as dialog, but would like to have the equivalent in a view that I could put in my wizard as "just another step".

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible without engineering your own non-standard save control.  Save location in windows is done via the common save file dialog control.  This is presented as a dialog and is not embeddable as an inline control.

My advice would be to follow the pattern laid out by other wizards

- The save location should be expressed with a text box where users can directly enter the save location
- To the right of the box is a Browse button which is hooked up to the save dialog

I would definitely recommend heavily against implementing your own Save control.  There are a lot of odd nuances handled by the standard Save dialog that you would almost certainly miss (network locations, share point, etc ...).  The result would be a non-standard and frustrating experience for end users

Comment: +1 for "I would definitely recommend heavily against implementing your own Save control."